want to get the Customer password at the time of Registration
Is there any way we get the customer password but not hashed!
I am trying this way but not getting
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class LogPassword implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $password = $observer->getEvent()->getData('password');

        if ($password) {
            $this->logger->info('Customer password: ' . $password);
        }
    }
}


You can use below code to get the password.
$password = $observer->getData('account_controller')->getRequest()->getParam('password');
